# How to feed and retrieve data from an ML model in android?

Tags: android, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am creating an android application using a machine learning model. I have a float array which contains only 0 and 1 [array = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ....}]. Now this array is to be given to the model to get the result. The model returns float array as result.
I am using following code to achieve the target but it returns this as a result [fl967ed4].

```
    try {

        MobileModel model = MobileModel.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

        // Creates inputs for reference.
        TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 1, 215}, 
                        DataType.FLOAT32);
        byte[] bytes = floatsToBytes(array);
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);

        inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

        // Runs model inference and gets result.
        MobileModel.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
        TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

        float[] data=outputFeature0.getFloatArray();


        // Releases model resources if no longer used.
        model.close();
        return data[0];
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Handle the exception
    }
```

Where am I doing wrong?
Can anyone help me with this? any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried data[0][0]? What does it give?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it still gives the same result as before.

Comment: From the output it seems that you are getting an object. Try to find out what dimensions this has to print the output corectly